# Sort out docker container permission when running silverstripe dev/build

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, silverstripe-4

I have created a fresh SilverStripe project using composer and I'm wanting to have my containers up and running via `docker-compose up`.

I have written a very basic Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM brettt89/silverstripe-web:7.4-apache

ENV DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/public
COPY . $DOCUMENT_ROOT
WORKDIR $DOCUMENT_ROOT
RUN chown www-data:www-data $DOCUMENT_ROOT
USER www-data
```

as well as a simple compose yaml file which specifies almost all the required services for it to work. here's what it looks like:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
   silverstripe:
      build:
         context: .
      volumes:
         - .:/var/www/html
      depends_on:
         - database
      environment:
         - DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
         - SS_TRUSTED_PROXY_IPS=*
         - SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE=dev
         - SS_DATABASE_SERVER=database
         - SS_DATABASE_NAME=SS_mysite
         - SS_DATABASE_USERNAME=root
         - SS_DATABASE_PASSWORD=
         - SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
         - SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
      ports:
        - 8088:80

   database:
      image: mysql:5.7
      environment:
         - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      volumes:
         - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
   db-data:
```

I can get my containers up and running. But when I go to `127.0.0.1:8080:/dev/build`, It is raising the mkdir():permission denied warning.

I can see my files in the container have 1000:1000 ownership which I assume is still root?

So wondering how I can fix this. I have seen examples of setting up things such that containers could be created via `docker build`, but I just want to be able to run things via `docker-compose up`.

I am using Ubuntu-20.04 and project has been created by $USER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest trick to fix this, for setting up your **local environment**, is to change your user UID from `1000` to `www-data` using the [usermod](https://linuxize.com/post/usermod-command-in-linux/#changing-a-user-uid) command:

```bash
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

then, of course, you can skip your last two lines.

You can find more info here:
https://blog.gougousis.net/file-permissions-the-painful-side-of-docker/

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed it and it is working now!!! just wondering why I can't use it for production?